# Pausing until button in pressed in Python

Tags: python, button, tkinter, pause

I'm trying to figure out how to pause code execution until a button is pressed in Tkinter. I have found examples of keyboard input but looking for a way to do the same with a button.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense in the context of a Tkinter application. A tkinter application is already constantly in a state of waiting. Can you write a _very short_ program that illustrates what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def mainfunction():
    #stuff your program is supposed to do


runmain = False

def runtheprogram():
    runmain = True

b1 = Button(root, text="Start", command=runtheprogram)
b1.pack()

if runmain:
    mainfunction()

root.mainloop()
```